# Meteor require a local package within another local package

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, require

I have two local packages in my Meteor app, my-ldap and my-activedirectory to login to my custom Active Directory environment.

They are based on the NPM packages and the activedirectory package was referenced from the ldap package as such:

```
ActiveDirectory = Npm.require('activedirectory');
```

Now that I want to use local packages, I can't use Npm.require, so how do I reference my local activedirectory from my local ldap?

```
ActiveDirectory = require('my-activedirectory');
```

The above just crashes the app.

Comment: `ActiveDirectory = Meteor.require('my-activedirectory');` also failed

Comment: i've tried unsuccessfully: `const ActiveDirectory = require('my-activedirectory');` `import * as ActiveDirectory from 'my-activedirectory';`

Comment: Are your packages Meteor packages or NPM packages?

Comment: @Khang they're both in my packages folder: `/packages/my-activedirectory` and `/packages/my-ldap`

Comment: I've got the package.js files set up with the Package.describe() set up also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to figure this out. My solution was to fork the node package repo on github and then publish an amended version to npm so I could keep the syntax:

```
ActiveDirectory = Npm.require('activedirectory-alt');
```